# Best practise in php when you want to extend two classess

Tags: php, oop

So I have a class for instance called foo and have two ways of storing data either in mongo or mysql.

at the moment I have something like

```
namespace vendor;

use bar;
use bar\mysql;

class foo extends bar\mongo {

}
```

now is there a better way to do it ? I know there is I just don't know which pattern it is if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle that can be applied is called:

> Favour composition over inheritance

That means in stead of inheriting from those objects, you give the class instances of those objects, and then does operations on it.

For example:

```
class Mysql
{
    function getItems($what)
    {
        //return items from mysql
    }
}

class MongoDB
{
    function getItems($what)
    {
        //return items from MongoDB    
    }    
}

class Foo
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->$db = $db;
    }

    public function getFooItems()
    {
        $this->db->getItems('foo')    
    }
}

$db = new Mysql();
$foo = new Foo($db)
$foo->getFooItems(); //Will operate on the mysql db

$db1 = new MongoDB();
$foo1 = new Foo($db1);
$foo1->getFooItems(); //Will operate on the MongoDB
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Do you have a link which explains how to do this in PHP ?

Comment: @OliverBS I have added an example to the answer.

Comment: Perfect :), I knew it was something like that ;)

Comment: You should be aware though, that this class structure violates basic OOP principles - since a "foo" is not a database, it's most probably a table.

Comment: @Flavius What specific 'OOP' principles are you talking about? This is just a small conceived example, demonstrating how to apply composition.